# Convert normal function to arrow function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am trying to convert the below function into arrow function using ES6,

```
$scope.sum = function(list, prop){
  return list.reduce( function(a, b){
     return a + b[prop];
  }, 0);
};
```

I tried below,

```
$scope.sum = (list,prop) =>  {return list.reduce((a,b) => {return (a+ b[prop])}, 0)};
```

throwing this error `Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined`

i am using in angular 1.5

Comment: That error would have to be happening because you're calling `$scope.sum()` somewhere with an undefined variable for the list.

Comment: What Herohtar is saying is that the error is independent of the arrow functions, it happens with the old function too.

Comment: Old function with $scope.sum  is working good, now I am trying to comment the old function and trying to do it in Es6...I think what ever i written in es6 syntax there is wrong i hope

Comment: The syntax of both of those functions is fine. The problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: then you must have changed something else, because the two implementations are eqivalent. Plus a more concise version of your code `$scope.sum = (list, prop) => list.reduce((a,b) => a+b[prop], 0);`

Comment: Thank you for your response...

Answer (score 4):

Your two functions are identical.

```
const sum1 = function(list, prop){ return list.reduce( function(a, b){ return a + b[prop];}, 0);};

const sum2 = (list,prop) =>  { return list.reduce((a,b) => {return (a+ b[prop])}, 0)};

const list = [{foo:1},{foo:2},{foo:3}]

console.log(sum1(list, 'foo'));
console.log(sum2(list, 'foo'));
```